# jQuery addClass not adding class?

Tags: jquery, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I have checked the forum but not found a solution that works for me. I have a simple .Net page WITH a masterpage. I am trying to implement a ValidationGroup with CustomValidators, with ClientSide validation.

The HTML is very straight forward (note, only on of the textboxes are currently validating, for test purposes only).

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 30px; margin-top: 100px;">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Test A" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ValidationGroup="vgroup1" />
</div>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvTxt1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgroup1" ControlToValidate="txt1" ClientValidationFunction="textValidate" ValidateEmptyText="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

The javascript is straight forward as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function textValidate(oSrc, args) {
    var isValid = false;
    // label label-warning
    isValid = args.Value.trim();

    if (isValid) { 
        $("#" + oSrc.controltovalidate).removeClass("has-error");    
    }
    else {
        $("#" + oSrc.controltovalidate).addClass("has-error");
    }

    args.IsValid = isValid;
}
</script>
```

`oSrc.controltovalidate` produces `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt1` (and I add the `#` manually), so the correct ID is generated. But, the class is not updated?

**UPDATE: when creating a custom class called .test in the head section, the class was added as it should be. So, what could cause the .has-error to not be applied?**

Any ideas?

Comment: `isValid = args.Value.trim();` what is the output of `args.Value.trim()` here? and where you called it you have not specified?

Comment: how do you know the class is not updated?

Comment: @Jai it returns true or false, depending if I add a value or not.

Comment: @Tamizh well, it is not reflected (should add red border and so on), and not visible in the page source?

Comment: what css you write for "has-error"? can you share

Comment: @Tamizh general Bootstrap CSS, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 0):

```
var isValid = false;
// label label-warning
isValid = args.Value.trim();

if (isValid) { 
    $("#" + oSrc.controltovalidate).removeClass("has-error");    
}
else {
    $("#" + oSrc.controltovalidate).addClass("has-error");
}
```

does the line 'isValid = args.Value.trim();' need to convert it's value to a boolean, true/false before passing to the if statement?

Comment: It enters the IF statement as supposed to. I added alerts() in each section previously to make sure. It just does not apply the class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the control needs to be wrapped in a div with the class FORM-GROUP. All objects in that group are then assigned the correct class.